# Showing actual units on a logarithmic scale

Tags: r, axis, logarithm

I have some data on a high resolution time scale that I am plotting using a logarithmic (log 10) scale, however I would like to show the actual time units on along the x axis, rather than the "log 10 (time)".

here's the data

```
time    ft
0.01    229
0.02    231
0.03    232
0.04    234
0.05    236
0.06    238
0.07    239
0.08    239
0.09    239
0.1     239
0.11    240
0.12    241
0.13    243
0.14    245
0.15    247
0.16    249
0.17    251
0.18    253
0.19    254
0.2     256
0.21    258
0.22    260
0.23    261
0.24    262
0.25    263
0.26    263
0.27    263
0.28    263
0.29    265
0.3     265
0.4     274
0.5     280
0.6     286
0.7     292
0.8     298
0.9     305
1       312
1.1     316
1.2     320
1.3     323
1.4     327
1.5     331
1.6     336
1.7     341
1.8     344
1.9     347
2       350
2.1     353
2.2     356
2.3     360
2.4     363
2.5     366
2.6     368
2.7     371
2.8     374
2.9     378
3       381
4       400
5       415
6       429
7       442
8       455
9       467
10      479
11      491
12      504
13      516
14      528
15      539
16      550
17      561
18      572
19      581
20      590
21      600
22      608
23      616
24      623
25      629
26      635
27      640
28      646
29      653
30      656
40      679
50      704
60      734
70      768
80      802
90      834
100     863
110     886
120     905
130     918
140     927
150     933
160     939
170     944
180     948
190     951
200     953
210     956
220     959
230     962
240     964
250     966
260     967
270     967
280     967
290     968
300     968
400     970
500     970
600     971
700     971
800     971
900     971
1000    970
```

Here's what I'd like it to look like

[image: OJIP curve]

Here's my code

```
ojip<-ojip
attach(ojip)
logt<-log10(ojip$time)
plot(logt,ojip$ft,xlab="Time (ms)",ylab="Fluorescence intensity",
     xaxt='n',yaxt='n',ylim=c(0,1300),cex.axis=0.8,cex.lab=0.8,
     pch=21,cex=0.8,font.lab=2,font.axis=2)
axis(side=2,at=seq(0,1200,200),cex.axis=0.7,font=2)
```

I'd like to show the actual time of the trace, as seen in the image, along the x axis using my data. Any solutions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using your logt variable,  just use `plot` 's built in capability to make logarithmic plots.

```
plot(ojip, xlab="Time (ms)",ylab="Fluorescence intensity",
     xaxt='n',yaxt='n',ylim=c(0,1300),cex.axis=0.8,cex.lab=0.8,
     pch=21,cex=0.8,font.lab=2,font.axis=2, log="x")
axis(side=2,at=seq(0,1200,200),cex.axis=0.7,font=2)
axis(side=1,at=10^(-2:3),cex.axis=0.7,font=2, 
    labels=c(0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000))
```

[image: Log plot]